# Behaviour of method toRealPath (class java.nio.file.Path)

Tags: java, path, nio

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) oracle java tutorial:

It says about the method toRealPath of the class Path:

> If true is passed to this method and the file system supports
>   symbolic links, this method resolves any symbolic links in the path.

What in the case that `false` is passed to the constructor but the path actually contains symbolik links?
How would the program  react at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the method does not take a boolean as argument, just the constant NOFOLLOW_LINKS or nothing... in the tutorial they mistook with true and false. However for the purpose of the question does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass nothing instead of NOFOLLOW_LINKS so it doesn't resolve symbolic links and just normalizes the path (remove unneccesary "..") and makes it absolute.

> When not resolving symbolic links and the preceding name [to the ".."]
>   is a symbolic link then the names are only removed if it guaranteed
>   that the resulting path will locate the same file as this path.

(javadoc)

Full description of the method with additional information, obtained from javadoc:

> Returns the real path of an existing file. The precise definition of
>   this method is implementation dependent but in general it derives from
>   this path, an absolute path that locates the same file as this path,
>   but with name elements that represent the actual name of the
>   directories and the file. For example, where filename comparisons on a
>   file system are case insensitive then the name elements represent the
>   names in their actual case. Additionally, the resulting path has
>   redundant name elements removed.
>
> If this path is relative then its absolute path is first obtained, as
>   if by invoking the toAbsolutePath method.
>
> The options array may be used to indicate how symbolic links are
>   handled. By default, symbolic links are resolved to their final
>   target. If the option NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then this method does
>   not resolve symbolic links. Some implementations allow special names
>   such as ".." to refer to the parent directory. When deriving the real
>   path, and a ".." (or equivalent) is preceded by a non-".." name then
>   an implementation will typically cause both names to be removed. When
>   not resolving symbolic links and the preceding name is a symbolic link
>   then the names are only removed if it guaranteed that the resulting
>   path will locate the same file as this path.

Source: javadoc: java se 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-